# Navigating to a particular anchor of a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I currently have two tabs in this page:

[image]

What I want to do is that whenever I navigate to this page, I want the page to default to opening the `Reviews` tab as opposed to the `Description` tab.

When you hover over the `Description` tab, you will see this URL pop up `localhost:8080/#tab-description`, and respectively, `localhost:8080/#tab-review`.

When I open this page, I want to be linked to the second tab, that is `#tab-review`, since right now, the default tab is the first one, `#tab-description`.

The redirection happens through a `View` called `order_info.tpl`, and I used this URL generation:

`<a href="<?php echo $product_url . $product['product_id'] . $tab_review; ?>" class="button"> FEEDBACK </a>`

`$product_url` is the URL I set in my Controller which is defined as `http://someurl:8080/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=`, where `$product['product_id']` is the product ID which is dynamically determined depending on what the product ID that particular page is.

**What I've tried:**

I attempted to add the `#tab-review` anchor to the end of my URL, but that did not solve my problem, i.e. `http://192.168.16.34:8080/index.php?route=product/product&path=772_774&product_id=1791#tab-review`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: i'll buy prawns for a cent each

Comment: What are you using for the tabs? jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the tab by initializing the widget with an active option.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    active: 1
});
```

Or set it after initialization:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Assuming you're using the [jQuery UI tab widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Hi @Kraiden. Would I be able to navigate to this particular tab purely from the URL? As far as I can tell, with your code, the Reviews tab will always be active regardless.

Comment: I don't think so. Don't quote me on this, but I think the reason anything shows up in the URL at all is more to do with the fact that you're using an <a> tag, and that's the default browser behavior. Which tab is actually shown is controlled by jQuery, which doesn't care about the URL. Again, I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Your best bet if you want control of which tab is opened, is possibly adding a parameter and control it on the PHP side. so your url would be something like http://192.168.16.34:8080/index.php?route=product/product&path=772_774&product_id=1791&active_tab=1